# Cliente Servidor Threads

Tags: java, thread

Na seguinte classe `SocketServidor` envio uma única thread com o `out` e o `in`, mas o suposto é esta classe conseguir enviar duas threads quando corre.

Supostamente tem de fazer isto:

> O servidor deverá funcionar em multi­threading, tendo para cada ligação ativa duas threads,  que designaremos por in e out:
>
> - in para receção de mensagens dos clientes (input stream) 
>     Esta thread estará bloqueada à espera de mensagens do cliente. As mensagens que o servidor recebe deverão ser guardadas numa estrutura em memória. Quando um dado utilizador tem mensagens novas, caso este esteja online, a thread out associada à sua ligação deverá ser notificada, por forma a processar a entrega das mensagens.
> - out para entrega de mensagens e notificações aos clientes (output stream) 
>     Esta thread estará em espera, tornando­ se ativa no momento em que existem mensagens novas ou notificações de entrega de mensagens relativas ao utilizador da ligação.

## `SocketServidor`

```
public class SocketServidor extends Thread{
    private ServerSocket servidorSocket;
    private Socket socket;
    private static final int PORTA = 8080;

    //HashMap recurso partilhado! (sempre que invocarmos este recurso temos de fazer synchronized)

    private Map<String, ObjectOutputStream> utilizadores = new HashMap<String, ObjectOutputStream>();  //utilizadores da aplicacao (online!)


    public SocketServidor(){
        try {
            servidorSocket = new ServerSocket(PORTA);               
            System.out.println("Estabelecer ligação TCP/IP no porto: " + PORTA);
            System.out.println("A aguardar conexão do cliente...");

            while(true){                                                            
                socket = servidorSocket.accept();                                   

                new Thread(new ListennerSocket(socket)).start();                        
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: E qual é a sua dúvida?

Comment: @NilsonUehara é fazer o servidor com multithreading, servidor com duas threads uma in e outra out, é que o que faço em cima é enviar so uma thread com o in e o out.

Comment: @NilsonUehara e é suposto o in e o out dar como esta em cima descrito, consegue me ajudar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Crie as duas threads

A primeira coisa errada com o código é que ele cria uma única thread para lidar com `in` e `out`.

Basicamente, você precisa do `ListenerSocket` (com apenas um `n`) para refazer a leitura do `in` e outra classe para lidar com o `out`.

Por exemplo:

```
new Thread(new ListenerSocket(socket.getInputStream())).start(); 
new Thread(new ReplierSocket(socket.getOutputStream())).start();
```

A thread que fica ouvindo fica automaticamente bloqueada até receber uma mensagem quando você chamada o método `readObject`, então a primeira parte do problema estará satisfeita.

## Use uma estrutura em memória adequada

No seu código não há uma estrutura em memória que armazena as mensagens.

Você armazena os `OutputStream`s dos utilizadores, mas isto está errado. Os `OutputStream`s dos utilizadores devem ser gerenciados pelas threads `out` criadas para cada um deles.

Minha sugestão é que você use um `ConcurrentHashMap` para evitar problemas de sincronização, caso contrário você terá que usar `synchronize` sempre que acessar o `HashMap`. Veja com seu professor se pode usar isso.

Em cada item do mapa, deve estar uma fila de mensagens que devem se entregues ao utilizador. Você pode usar `ArrayDeque` com sincronização manual ou `ArrayBlockingQueue` para sincronização automática.

Então seu mapa seria algo como:

```
private Map<String, ObjectOutputStream> mensagensAEntregar = new HashMap<String, ArrayDeque<Mensagem>();
```

## Como a sincronização de mensagens pode acontecer

Quando criar as threads, adicione no mapa de mensagens a entregar uma fila vazia de mensagens.

Na thread de output, você deve então recuperar a lista e chamar o método `wait()` **da lista** para que a thread seja bloqueada. Se for `ArrayBlockingQueue`, basta chamar o método `take()` e o bloqueio ocorrerá automaticamente até uma mensagem ser recebida.

Na thread de leitura, ao receber uma mensagem, você percorre todos os valores do mapa, mais ou menos como está fazendo, adiciona a mensagem na fila e então chama o método `nofityAll()` **da lista** para acordar as threads bloqueadas por `wait()`. Se for `ArrayBlockingQueue` não precisa fazer nada pois o método `take()` irá retornar automaticamente.

Note que `wait()` e `notify()` ou `notifyAll()` somente funcionam se você chamar no mesmo objeto.

## Sinalizando a saída de um utilizador

Quando o utilizador sair, você precisa interromper as duas threads. Isso significa que você precisa despertá-las e sinalizar de alguma forma para que elas saiam do loop.

No caso do input é fácil, pois você vai receber a mensagem, avisar os utilizadores e sair do loop.

No caso do output, você pode colocar uma flag na mensagem dizendo que é uma mensagem de saída e assim sair do loop sem mandar a mensagem.

## Considerações

Mesmo com os equívocos da implementação, não creio que você está longe de conseguir fazer uma boa implementação.

Sugiro que reescreva seu código seguindo minhas dicas acima e talvez outras dicas de outros usuários. Depois você pode editar sua questão com o novo código (sem remover o primeiro) ou mesmo criar outras perguntas sobre problemas mais específicos que enfrentar.